# I'm facing problems connecting express to Rabbit MQ

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, rabbitmq, backend

On visiting local host 3000 I get Cannot GET / before using postman.

during the process of sending POST request in postman to the local host my program fails  and I get this Error

`node:internal/process/promises:288
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5672
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16) {
errno: -61,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 5672`

```
config.js
----------

module.exports = {
  rabbitMQ: {
    url: "amqp://localhost",
    exchangeName: "logExchange",
  },
};


Producer.js
-----------

const amqp = require("amqplib");
const config = require("./config");

//step 1 : Connect to the rabbitmq server
//step 2 : Create a new channel on that connection
//step 3 : Create the exchange
//step 4 : Publish the message to the exchange with a routing key

class Producer {
  channel;

  async createChannel() {
    const connection = await amqp.connect(config.rabbitMQ.url);
    this.channel = await connection.createChannel();
  }

  async publishMessage(routingKey, message) {
    if (!this.channel) {
      await this.createChannel();
    }

    const exchangeName = config.rabbitMQ.exchangeName;
    await this.channel.assertExchange(exchangeName, "direct");

    const logDetails = {
      logType: routingKey,
      message: message,
      dateTime: new Date(),
    };
    await this.channel.publish(
      exchangeName,
      routingKey,
      Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(logDetails))
    );

    console.log(
      `The new ${routingKey} log is sent to exchange ${exchangeName}`
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Producer;




Server.js
----------


`const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const Producer = require("./producer");
const producer = new Producer();

app.use(bodyParser.json("application/json"));

app.post("/sendLog", async (req, res, next) => {
  await producer.publishMessage(req.body.logType, req.body.message);
  res.send();
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started...");
});`
```

I am a Junior Intern ad was following along an youtube video  by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igaVS0S1hA4  by Computerix to help me understand the concepts

I tried restarting the rabbitMQ and express server and running it on different ports but didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is Big Picture

[image]

Postman -> Express Server -> RabbitMQ -> node.js

#1 Postman send message to Express with `Message Types` and `payload` by POST call

#2 Express Server forward message to Rabbit MQ by `publish`

#3 RabbitMQ - push the messages into own [`message queue`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html)

#4 Each `consumer` received own message from RabbitMQ. It was binned before.

There are many complex options(order, priority) but in here talking about basic and simple model.

#### Steps

We needs following three steps.
[image]

#### #1 : Install

1.1 [docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) (easy way to container to run RabbitMQ)

1.2 [node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

1.3 demo source

```
git clone https://github.com/charbelh3/RabbitMQ-Logger-Example.git
```

File structure
[image]

1.4 install node library

At `RabbitMQ-Logger-Example\infoMS` directory

```
npm install amqplib
```

At `RabbitMQ-Logger-Example\loggerMS` directory

```
npm install amqplib express body-parser
```

At `RabbitMQ-Logger-Example\warningAndErrorMS` directory

```
npm install amqplib
```

1.5 Install [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

1.6 Install [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) - I will using git bash terminal. It similar bash terminal in Linux - If you using Linux, skip this.

[image]

#### #2 : Binding

2.1 running RabbitMQ

Save this code as `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management-alpine
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
    volumes:
        - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
        - ~/.docker-conf/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
        - rabbitmq_go_net

networks:
  rabbitmq_go_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Run it

```
docker compose up
```

If docker compose version 1.x

```
docker-compose up
```

Open your browser with this URL

```
http://localhost:15672/
```

[image]

2.2 Run express and all node.js

At `RabbitMQ-Logger-Example\infoMS` directory

```
node app.js
```

At `RabbitMQ-Logger-Example\loggerMS` directory

```
node server.js
```

At `RabbitMQ-Logger-Example\warningAndErrorMS` directory

```
node app.js
```

Now ready to go

#### #3 : Message

Run Postman,

#1 Make own collection

#2 Make Three requests

[image]

One of Request - `Send Info Message`

[image]

#1 Select `POST` method

#2 Enter URL

```
localhost:3000/sendLog
```

#3 Click `Body` Tab

#4 Select `Raw` radio button

#5 Enter message into `body`

```
{
    "logType" : "Info",
    "message" : "I am Info message"
}
```

#6 Select `JSON`

#7 Press `Send` Button

If you see [image], ***You are success!***

Other two different type message is same content
Just difference is `logType`'s value.

`Send Warning Message` Request

For `Warning`

```
{
    "logType" : "Warning",
    "message" : "I am Warning message"
}
```

`Send Error Message` Request

For `Error`

```
{
    "logType" : "Error",
    "message" : "I am Error message"
}
```

This is real screen all of things!

[image]

If you browser, RabbitMQ content, you found many things.

This is one of it for `Info` channel information.
[image]

If want to terminate RabbitMQ

```
CTRL+C
docker compose down
```

Enjoy RabbitMQ!